# Custom module's layout not redering products in frontpage..blank page no errors

Tags: magento2

I have 3 modules overridden from

CatalogSearch,

Catalog and

LayeredNaviagation

In my 4th module, i just need to render the products after hitting the below URL(page shows blank) which is rendering from the 1st 3 modules properly.

http://localhost:1338/magento2x_3/merchandisingpage/result/index/product/test

**UPDATED**

**etc/frontend/router**

```
route id="merchandisingpage" frontName="merchandisingpage"
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
//Have given the preference type for all the modules overridden in 1st 3 modules.
//Need clarification as this can be done!
```

**4th module Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php**

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   public function execute()
   {
      $query = $this->request->getParam('q');   
    $q = $this->request; 
    $re =  array();
    $re = $q->getParams();   

    $re['filters'] = true;
    $re['q'] = $re['product'];  
     unset($re['product']);
    $payload = $re;  
      ....
   }
}
```

**\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\merchandisingpage_result_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <action method="setTitle">
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Merchandising</argument>
    </action>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="search.result">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::result.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock class=" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module2::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock class=" name="product_list_toolbar" >
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module3::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I need to get the products rendered in frontpage.

I get blank screen, without errors or exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile the Magento project::

`sudo php /[your project dir like : var/www/project_name]/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: i ran setup upgrade @Aashish..i dont think we need to run di:compile each time...its not working..i still get blank page

Comment: After upgrade or making any di.xml its necessary to run compilation.

Comment: I ran...i still get blank page after di:compile, clear var gen, cache